# Multiple piwik tracking js

Tags: javascript, matomo, javascript-namespaces

I have wordpress plugin which outputs Piwik tracking js on client site:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var _paq = _paq || [];
      _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
      _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
      (function() {
        var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https" : "http") + "://piwik.com//";
        _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
        _paq.push(['setSiteId', 1]);
        var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; g.type='text/javascript';
        g.defer=true; g.async=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
      })();

    </script>
    <noscript><p><img src="http://piwik.com/piwik.php?idsite=1" style="border:0" alt="" /></p></noscript>
```

The issue is that some of clients already use their own piwik tracking js, and it ends up with two piwik tracking JS outputted on their site.

Then there is conflict, because two tracking JS are writing to the same JS object "_paq"

So it would be great if there is some sollution to this like noConflict() for jQuery.

So would need the way to tell to "piwik.js" which I am including to not read from "_paq" and to read from some my custom object. So far, as I can see I would need to modify piwik.js for that.

I saw that piwik has option for multiple tracking : [Multiple Piwik trackers](https://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide#multiple-piwik-trackers)

But I don't have control of another tracking code, I have only control of tracking JS outputed from my plugin.

So any, help would be great for this.

Comment: Can you have yours use a custom variable (as the Multiple Piwik Trackers sections suggests) and let the clients' use the default _paq?

Comment: I am trying that. The only issue is that I need to load piwik.js to the site, and client will also load it's own piwik.js. Now I don't know how to control from which piwik.js will be instanced tracker in my code with "Piwik.getTracker". Because if it use clients' piwik.js and he is using old version of Piwik I will not have some piwik methods

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to workaround this problem has been changing the name  (choose a weird one) of the _paq variable in piwik.js and loading piwik.js synchronously.

No more collisions after that